# What happens if local flight to a hub airport gets delayed and I have a connection at the hub airport

Tags: etihad

I will be travelling from a small city to a hub airport to catch Etihad Airways flight to Abu Dhabi. Travel from the small city to the hub is by a local airline because Etihad doesn't land at the small city. The whole journey from start to finish is on a single ticket:

```
Local city - hub : local airline
hub - Abu Dhabi: Etihad Airways
All of these on a single ticket.
```

If my flight gets delayed at the small city due to weather and I miss my connection at the hub, does Etihad reschedule me free of charge or do I lose my ticket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your contract with Etihad is to get you from 'small city' to Abu Dhabi - if for whatever reason, other than your own fault, they fail to do so you should receive a refund, i.e. will not 'lose my ticket'. Though it is much more likely that arrangements will be made to transport you, even though not at quite the schedule you expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply pnuts. That would be true even in the case when the local airline itself is not Etihad on the first leg?

Also, how can I verify whether the ticket that I have is really a single ticket or not? Because it is the definition of a single ticket which would in fact determine the outcome if such a scenario does take place, correct?

Comment: yes your answer is good. I am just wondering how to find out if it is really a single ticket? I had my travel agent do the whole booking but i am unsure what exactly defines a single ticket?

Comment: @Jeremy It's a single ticket if you bought it in one transaction with the agent. This is a very normal arrangement and you will be rerouted probably on the next available Etihad flight.